# What is Class<?> vc or JavaType valueType used for in the constructor of Jackson's StdDeserializer

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-modules

I am making a custom deserializer (extending `StdDeserializer`) using the [Jackson JSON library](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/std/StdDeserializer.html) and I can't figure out what the purpose of the constructor parameters are. What is `Class<?>` or `JavaType valueType` used for by Jackson? Is it just because Java doesn't have reified generics and Jackson needs more information about the generic type you're making an instance of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jackson matches JSON structures with java classes. Just like JAXB maps java classes to XSD-s.

So, this `Class<?>` (or JavaType) defines which java class belongs to this deserializer. These java classes can be anything that have the right annotations, like `@JsonProperty`.

Another question: why is this class generic? This is so because `[java.lang.Class][1]` is generic. If you want to do it correctly, then you specify it like this:

```
StdDeserializer serializer = new StdDeserializer(YourClass.class);
```

The point is that the `StdSerializer` *does not bound* the classes you can specify.

Comment: But if you know you have a generic of type T isn't that enough to name the class type? You know it is Class<T>, so you don't need the class to be passed in seperatly.

Comment: The generic type `T` is enough if you need it only at **compile time**. If you need it at **runtime** too, then you need a runtime class token. E.g. the `java.util.EnumSet` uses it: `EnumSet.noneOf(YourEnum.class)`